# Network speed restrictions

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

Started working in a new company and observing a weird situation with network latency here (details below)

Environment: I'm on ubuntu 12.04 box (company restrictions for developer machines to use the same OS version as production boxes), located in Russia, our network is configured to use US DNS servers.

So, here is the weirdness:
Download from company's vcs and extenal resources is about 50KB/sec. Example:
Started *'svn co svn://mycompany/svn/trunk'* and *'wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.7-all.zip'* from the command line, monitored bandwidth via the [nethogs tool](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/), it shows the results below:

```
sudo nethogs -d 10 eth0

NetHogs version 0.8.0

PID   USER   PROGRAM  DEV   SENT   RECEIVED       
9140  denis  wget     eth0  0.380  64.585 KB/sec
7395  denis  svn      eth0  1.526  40.379 KB/sec
...
```

Ensured that there is no vpn, just a regular ethernet connection:

```
denis@denis-zhdanov-desktop:~/Downloads/tmp$ nmcli con status
NAME                 UUID        DEVICES  DEFAULT    VPN   MASTER-PATH                                 
Wired connection  1  <my-uuid>   eth0       yes      no    not set
```

Tried to switch to google DNS (8.8.8.8), flush local dns cache and re-download the same resource - shows the same bandwidth.

My colleagues told me that there is a problem with office's provider - bad download speed. However, an attempt to install ubuntu updates via updates manager showed bandwidth about 40 times higher:

```
PID   USER   PROGRAM                    DEV   SENT   RECEIVED
25009 root   /usr/lib/apt/methods/http  eth0  0.000  2148.000 KB/sec
```

I thought that it might be somehow related to the fact that the process was started from the root (kind of stupid but I encountered a number of stupid-at-first-sight situations before), so, tried to download the same resource as a root but got the same 50KB/sec.

Also a strange thing is that speedtest.net shows that my download speed is about 40Mbps (Paris), 20Mbps (Berlin), 35Mbps (Boston). All of those numbers are a way higher than what I see on the local machine.

Any thoughts on what might cause that behavior?

Regards, Denis

Comment: Google DNS? Flushing DNS cache? DNS doesn't affect your bandwidth in any way...

Comment: Are the different DNS nameservers resolving the same hosts to the same IP addresses?

Comment: Not sure, I thought it might be the case for CDN resources - different hosts are offered based on DNS server address but yes, that should affect latency but not bandwidth

Comment: It depends if the different IPs are pointing to different locations with different upload bandwiths, but if the IP addresses were the same, then I agree with @grawity, the DNS should have nothing to do with this.

Comment: Is it possible one of the local gateways has tc (traffic control) active?

Comment: not sure about traffic control, don't have access to the office's provider

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is here. What you have described could be perfectly normal internet behaviour, or could be any of a hundred problems. Yet you haven't shown any information or diagnostics relating to network latency whatsoever.

Comment: The problem is that there is a discrepancy between low download speed for most of the resources I tried, high download speed for ubuntu packages and high download speed results shown by speedtest.net